# Keep in process' Memory json and file overwrite vs. json load and dump

Tags: python, json, performance

I have a large scale scraper, where each time it scrapes a website, it overwrite and dumps the json to a file, throughout the process, and keeps the actual json (as a dictionary) in the process' memory (i.e. it doesn't load and then dump).

Here's some reference to my current approach:

```
        records['records']['record'].append(record)  # record is a large sub-json
        with open(JSON_FILE, "w") as f:
            json.dump(records, f, indent=4)
```

I've been wanted to know, what is more time efficient - to load the json file to the process, then change the json and dump to file, or to do what I've done (i.e. to keep the json in memory, change it, and then overwrite the file)?
is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't quiet understand. For each new record the file needs to be rewritten? Then after loading the previous file the state would be the same as if you kept the previous `records` object. That just seems like additional work.

Comment: @eukaryota yes, the file is rewritten, so the question is, which is faster - loading the and then changing the json and dump, or rewriting the file.

Comment: But you already have the json in memory, so what reasons do you have in mind for which reloading could be faster?

Comment: If reloading is faster, I won't leave all the json in memory, just the current record